# Exporting a SSRS 2008 report to RTF

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rtf

I am using Microsoft.ReportViewer to display SSRS reports from my C# desktop application. The ReportViewr by default provides the 3 modes of export features, 1. Excel. 2. Word, 3. PDF. Now we want another export capability of RTF. Does any one have any idea how to convert the SSRS reports to RTF format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Reporting Services does not support RTF as a rendering format out of the box. If you want this functionality you have two options:

1) Develop a [custom rendering extension](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153624.aspx)

or

2) Buy a third-party solution, for example [this one](http://www.aspose.com/reporting-services/word-component.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think i should be using the fist option. I see that the custom rendering extension is provided in Sql Server 2012. I am rather using 2008 version. Can i still use Custom Rendering Extension for RTF conversion?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry that link was to the SQL 2012 version, but the principle is the same for SQL 2008 - here's the correct link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153624%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Also note that creating a custom rendering extension is a complex programming task. You should evaluate the cost of trying to create your own vs. buying an existing solution before starting.

Answer (score 0):

If you can export it to a word file, you can use the word interop to read the file, select all, copy and paste to a richtextbox. You can get the rtf format from the RTF property of the richtextbox.

Comment: I want to do the conversion programatically. There are around 1000 reports. Each time when i open report i should have a feature to export it to RTF.